# How to get all IHTMLStyle attributes of an IHTMLElement?

Tags: css, delphi, dom, mshtml, twebbrowser

I use the below code:

```
const
  HTML_DOC =
    '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">' +
    '<BODY><P id="p1" style="width: 440px; height: 344px; margin: 3px 2px; float: left;">test</P></BODY>' +
    '</HTML>';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HTMLTxtRange: IHTMLTxtRange;
  HTMLDocument: IHTMLDocument2;
  HTMLElement: IHTMLElement;
  HTMLStyle: IHTMLStyle;
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank');
  while WebBrowser1.ReadyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
    Application.ProcessMessages;

  HTMLDocument := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  HTMLTxtRange := (HTMLDocument.body as IHTMLBodyElement).createTextRange;
  HTMLTxtRange.PasteHTML(HTML_DOC);    

  HTMLElement := (HTMLDocument as IHTMLDocument3).getElementById('p1');
  if Assigned(HTMLElement) then
  begin
    HTMLStyle := HTMLElement.style {as IHTMLStyle2};
    Memo1.Lines.Add(HTMLStyle.cssText);  // MARGIN: 3px 2px; WIDTH: 440px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 344px
    Memo1.Lines.Add(HTMLStyle.getAttribute('margin', 0)); // 3px 2px
  end;    
end;
```

My question is: how can I get a list of available style attributes using DOM collection without manually parsing `HTMLStyle.cssText` i.e. expected output:

```
MARGIN
WIDTH
FLOAT
HEIGHT
```

Comment: I don't see any properties that do what you want. Parsing this with a TStringList is a nobrainer though :)

Comment: @whosrdaddy, I've already used `TStringList` to parse it, changed `:` to `=` to maintain a key/value, but I don't like this solution. I was hopping that I've missed something and there is such collection available :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IHTMLStyle` (or its descendants) do not expose that kind of functionality.  However, since `IHTMLStyle` does implement the `IDispatch` interface, you can try using `IDispatch.GetTypeInfo()` to get an `ITypeInfo` interface describing the style object and then iterate through its available properties, using `IDispatch.Invoke()` to read the value of each property you discover.  However, if `GetTypeInfo()` does not return a viable `ITypeInfo`, then you are out of luck, and will have to parse the `IHTMLStyle.cssText` instead.

Comment: I don't see how iterating through the properties can help in this situation... suppose I find `marginLeft` property. should I assume I have a `margin-top` style attribute? or maybe I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: When you find a property, read its value and check if it is empty before using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var win7: ihtmlwindow7;
     css: ihtmlcssstyledeclaration;
begin
  Win7:= (webbrowser1.document as ihtmldocument2).parentwindow as ihtmlwindow7;
  css:= win7.getcomputedstyle(htmlelement as ihtmldomnode);

  for... css.length
   css.item
```